# JavaScript Setter bug found?

Tags: javascript

Hy I wrote a quick and dirty list ui in js and html that can be filtered:
https://jsfiddle.net/maxbit89/2jab4fa4/

So the usage of this looks like this (Fiddle line: 96):

```
var list = new ui_list(document.body, 200, 300, "Test");
var encoder = function(dom, value) {
  console.log("begin encoding");
  console.log(value)
  dom.innerHTML = value.n;
}

list.add({'n': 1}, function() {
    this.value.n++;
    console.log(this.value.n);
//    this.value = this.value;
}, encoder);
```

So what this basicaly does is create a List and adds a Element to it that has an Object: {'n': 1} as a value and a onClickHandler(second parameter on list.add) wich should increase the value by 1 (fiddle line: 104)

But it won't do this untill you uncomment the line 106 in the fiddle.
(Tested with FireFox 50.1.0, and Edge Browser)

**Has any body an idea why js behaves like this?**
In a much simplier example this works just fine:

```
var myObj= {
    'onvalueChange' : function() {
        console.log('value changed');
    },
    'print' : function() {
          console.log('value:');
        console.log(this.value);
        console.log(this.value.n);
    }
};

Object.defineProperty(myObj, "value", {
    get: function() { return this._value; },
   set: function(value) {
        this.onvalueChange();
        this._value = value;
    }
});

myObj.value = {'n' : 1};

myObj.value.n++;

myObj.print();
```

Comment: you can only "watch" properties one-level deep; change to sub-properties don't use the setter/getters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have the setter defined like this:

```
set: function (value) {
    this.encoder(this, value);
    this._value = value;
}
```

that means that every time the value is set, the encoder will be called with the new value to update the equivalent DOM element.

But then inside the event listener function you have:

```
function() {
    this.value.n++;
    console.log(this.value.n);
    //this.value = this.value;
}
```

where you think that `this.value.n++` is setting the value (means it calls the setter which means the encoder will be called to update the DOM element). But it's not true. `this.value.n++` is actually calling the getter. To explain more this:

```
this.value.n++;
```

is the same as:

```
var t = this.value; // call the getter
t.n++; // neither call the getter nor the setter. It just uses the reference (to the object) returned by the getter to set n
```

So, when you uncomment the line `this.value = this.value;`, the setter gets called, and the encoder gets called to update the DOM element.

So to fix the issue you have to either:

- Make a call inside the getter to the encoder as you did for the setter (but this solution is very hacky as it will update the DOM element on every getter call even if nothing is being set).
- Change this `this.value.n++;` to actually call the setter like: `this.value = {n: this.value.n + 1};` (but this is hacky too as if value has a lot of key-value pairs then you have to enlist them all here just to set `n`).
- Call the encoder inside the event listener which will be the best way to do it (or if you don't want to pass the parameters to it make another function (for example `this.callEncoder()`) that will call it and [you] call the new function instead inside the event listener).

Comment: Ok thats a strange behavior :s if some one has the same issue here is a smaller example: https://jsfiddle.net/maxbit89/ehf3mzhn/

Comment: * With strange behavior i mean it is probably usless cause you can't really use this in frameworks when an "end user" has no clue if there is a getter/setter involved and he runs into this issue?.

Comment: @maxbit89 then you have to redesign this. As you are already assuming that the user should know how to set the value using `this.value.n++`.